# Will Elasticsearch remove exist filter cache after I set cache in query to false

Tags: caching, elasticsearch

Say I have a filter in query like this:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : { 
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { 
                    "price" : 20
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to the official doc, there will be a filter cache associated to the key "price".
One day, I change the query as follow:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : { 
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { 
                    "price" : 20,
                    "_cache" : false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Will Elasticsearch automatically remove the exist cache?

Comment: Setting `"_cache" : false` has been deprecated as of ES 2.x and support for it will be removed in ES 5.x. Starting with ES 2.x, it has a much smarter cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure. It will probably be removed eventually but probably not immediately. It doesn't really matter however as setting _cache = false will tell elastic search to not use the cache even if it is technically still there.  If you want to clear the cache manually there's an API for it.

Here is an example:`curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/_cache/clear`

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-clearcache.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12635780)

Comment: Thanks! I updated my answer to contain the relevant information from the link